# Высота и ширина картинки до сохранения на диск

Tags: php, изображения

Можно ли узнать размеры изображения пока оно ещё находится в массиве $_FILES, т.е. до его сохранения на сервер? Мне надо загружать картинки так, чтобы в их именах были их размеры.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list($imgWidth,  $imgHeight) = getimagesize($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);
```

где $imgWidth и $imgHeight, соответственно, ширина и высота

Answer (score 3):

Файлы, находящиеся в массиве `$_FILES` уже загружены на сервер, правда как временные файлы. Ключ, содержащий путь до временного файла называется `tmp_name`. Вам остается только узнать размер картинки ([getimagesize()](http://www.php.su/getimagesize)) и "загрузить" изображение с нужным вам именем.

Comment: Сделал. Не могу теперь справится с ошибкой
Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Comment: @Fangog ага..., видимо временный файл лежит там, где его не достать. Тогда уж либо ковыряйте настройки сервера, либо сначала заливайте файл с каким-нибудь рандомным именем, а потом переименовывайте. А может еще кто-нибудь свою идею предложит.